# Show Input Dropdown for Each Select

Tags: jquery, class, select, input

I have a table being generated from a database and I want to have a dropdown select for each of them. I have no trouble in makring the dropdown but I want one of the select options to show a input field.

Currently, when you select the input field option "move", it shows the input field for all my results, but it should only show it for that specific listing.

Thanks in advance!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLTum/

HTML:

```
<select class='review_select' style='width:100px;'>
<option value='select'>-Select-</option>
<option value='disable'>Disable</option>
<option value='move'>Move</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class='review_select' style='width:100px;'>
<option value='select'>-Select-</option>
<option value='disable'>Disable</option>
<option value='move'>Move</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select class='review_select' style='width:100px;'>
<option value='select'>-Select-</option>
<option value='disable'>Disable</option>
<option value='move'>Move</option>
</select>

<div class='move_to' style='display:none;'>
<p>Rooftop ID</p>
<input type="text" style='width:60px;'/>
<button style='position:absolute; margin-left:8px;'>Go</button>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.review_select').bind('change', function() {
 var value = $(this).val(); // get selected value
 if (value == 'select') {
     $('.move_to').css("display", "none");
 }
 if (value != 'move' && value != 'select') {
     $('.move_to').css("display", "none");
     if (window.confirm('Disable Review Record?')) {
         window.location = value;
     }
 }
 if (value == 'move') {
     $('.move_to').css("display", "");
 }
 return false;
});
```

Comment: Would probably help if you posted the actual table HTML instead of just the selects.

Comment: I am kind of confuse with the question.What actually the behaviour required?

Comment: Need the ability to add a input field for each item. My JS fiddle only shows the same input no matter what item's select you use.

Comment: For which option 'move', do you want to get input field?

Comment: So basically you want editable options.

Comment: Dont get what you want. you want for every dropdownlist a different input-field?